# sed to find and transform binary number representation

Tags: sed, binary, transform, inline, representation

I have a file with binary numbers that I would like to alter inline with sed -i.

The file has lines like this:

```
  00018342 0000           dc.b   11010101b
```

So I would like to have it represented this way:

```
  00018342 0000           dc.b   %11010101
```

I tried this:

`sed -e 's/[[:digit:]]\+\b/%&/g' test.txt`

I thought that would only prepend a '%' if it found actual digits preceded by a 'b'.  But instead it output this:

```
  %00018342 %0000           dc.b    11010101b
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  And how would I delete the 'b' after the '%' is prepended?

Comment: You will have to use a capture group because `&` represents complete match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed 's/\b\([01]\+\)b\b/%\1/g' file
```

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/tD6OMU):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='  00018342 0000           dc.b   11010101b'
sed 's/\b\([01]\+\)b\b/%\1/g' <<< "$s"
# =>   00018342 0000           dc.b   %11010101
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\([01]\+\)` - Group 1: one or more `1` or `0` digits
- `b` - a `b` letter
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `%\1` - the replacement is a `%` char + the Group 1 value.

A POSIX ERE version is `sed -E 's/\b([01]+)b\b/%\1/g' file`.

Comment: Thank you, that works as expected.  Can the [01] portion be changed to [0123456789ABCDEF] to handle converting hex numbers like A4h into $A4? (assuming I change the 'b' to 'h' and the '%' to '$' of course)

Comment: @TrevorActon I think you can simply use `sed 's/\b\(\([[:xdigit:]]\{2\}\)\+\)h\b/$\1/g'`. The `xdigit` character class is meant to match hexadecimal values. And I believe they should be even numbers, so I suggest matching one or more occurrences of two hex symbols before a `h`.